# Videos in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have my sharepoint site. My requirement is to efficiently show videos in my site (like the one in youtube). But I don't know what should be ideal approach to store videos.

FYI: I would have repository of around 10000 videos.

Comment: You might want to clarify this a bit so you get the most appropriate answer, "like the one in youtube". This implies that you want to display youtube videos (based on bandwidth comment) but you also imply that you want to store them (repository).

Comment: My look and feel should be similar to the one in youtube. But implementation is in Sharepoint. Sorry for miscommunication.

Comment: Has anyone worked with RBS (Remote BLOB storage)? Can anyone guide me?

Comment: Can we use MMPCM for SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 5):

The Asset Library is indeed the recommended place where you should store media assets, because of its Content Types attached allowing automatic playback of content with integrated Silverlight components. Just be aware that Silverlight media player by default only does Caching (simple buffering) while playing and NOT streaming. You would need to install on your Front Ends IIS Extensions for Media streaming (http://www.iis.net/download/SmoothStreaming).
This will drastically improve both client & server performance.

The strategy of how many libraries you create it depends on many aspects, have a look here to get some planning ideas http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee414276.aspx

You should also consider BLOB caching enabled (to improve Web Front End performance and avoid back-end roundtrips), then probably some RBS (Remote BLOB Storage) planning to avoid storing all that content in your databases, but rather externalize to physical storage, reducing your content databases sizes.

Answer (score 2):

We had similar issues with bandwidth and storage and decided to use a third party to handle streaming and video storage.  We created a content type that included the url of the video, along with some other fields that could be used by search, etc.  We created a video player web part that handles adding the media item along with uploading the video to the third party along with playing the video for the user.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Joyal4 you can use create a new asset library in SharePoint 2010.

This video is part of a how to create asset library.

check this link

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVvn_nw7RcE

Comment: But I can't store 10000 videos in my asset library. My bandwidth would go haywire

Answer (score 0):

I youtube is an option than i would store the files there as you just need to add the youtube webpart and link them up (store urls in a list among other things)

http://spyoutube.codeplex.com/

http://spandps.com/2011/10/19/sharepoint-you-tube-web-part-now-up-on-codeplex-sp2010-ps2010-projectserver-msproject/

otherwise

the blob option would be best if you were to host the videos.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286318(v=office.14).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/spazuretrainingcourse_spblobstorageazure.aspx

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely look into RBS. This is probably your best bet. You can use the native FILESTREAM solution but it is rather limited. There are a lot of providers that have RBS solutions that tie into SharePoint (MetaLogix StoragePoint being one).

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the following links,

**http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2013/03/29/corporate-youtube-and-video-delivery-via-sharepoint-2013.aspx**

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/steve_fox/archive/2012/08/05/sharepoint-2013-and-windows-azure-media-services.aspx

Hope this helps you!!!

Comment: These links are applicable to the question, and demonstrate a possible solution to the original question -- but you should at least summarize some of their content (quotes are fine) on this website so that the answer makes sense in context and in case either of those blogs are ever taken down the information will remain.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Microsoft Stream](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/microsoft-stream).  It is included with the following O365 plans:

- Microsoft 365 Apps for Enterprise
- Office 365 E1
- Office 365 E3
- Office 365 E5